# NSPredicate for many - to - many relationship

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have two entities ***Offers*** and ***Categories*** which are connected via a many - to - many relationship.

In the entity ***Offers*** there is a boolean attribute called played and *hasCategories* which is the relationship with ***Categories***.

Also in the entity ***Categories*** there is a boolean attribute called *following*.

I want to fetch all ***Offers*** which *played = true* and all its categories has *following = true*

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
NSPredicate(format:"played = TRUE AND SUBQUERY(hasCategories, $c, $c.following = FALSE).@count = 0")
```

The subquery checks that none of the related categories has `following == false`.

Comment: Can you explain me what $c means ?

Comment: @ChristosHadjikyriacou: It is a "local loop variable" and set in turn to each element of the "hasCategories" relation. (Unfortunately, SUBQUERY is not well-documented. You'll find more examples on SO.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. But its not working. I did something like this insted fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "played == NO and ANY hasCategories IN %@",Category.getAllFollowingCategories(self.managedObjectContext)) but now i have to close and reopen the app for the results to appear

Comment: It gives me zero results back.

Comment: @ChristosHadjikyriacou: Strange. I made a quick test and it worked as expected for me.

Comment: Now its working , i changed following = TRUE. Thank you and sorry for the stupid mistake